# Ignore comments (#) using sed, but keep the lines untouched

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have a config file that I want to basically edit the uncommented lines, but not the commented lines.  I'm using `sed`.

For example, I have a file called file.txt:

```
test
# test
# test
test
```

I want to replace "test" with "TEST" but do NOT touch the commented lines.  Final output should show:

```
TEST
# test
# test
TEST
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
sed '/^#/!s/test/TEST/g' /path/to/infile
```

#### Output

```
$ sed '/^#/!s/test/TEST/g' infile
TEST
# test
# test
TEST
```

*Note: If your only requirement for a comment is that the very first non-whitespace character is a `#`, then you can use:

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*#/!s/test/TEST/g' /path/to/infile
```

#### Output

```
$ sed '/^[[:space:]]*#/!s/test/TEST/g' infile
TEST
# test
 # test
TEST
```

Comment: Tidy. I would have expected awk to be more readable, but that's nice.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a `sed` expert, but the regexp to match those lines will look *something* like this:

`^[^#].*test`

- `^` - beginning of line
- `[^#]` - first character, anything except #
- `.*` - some more characters, undefined
- `test` - the string you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

To ignore comments that start with a `#` when doing a substitution, you can use the following command:

```
sed -r 'h;s/[^#]*//1;x;s/#.*//;(substitution command);G;s/(.*)\n/\1/' file.txt
```

In your case it becomes:

```
sed -r 'h;s/[^#]*//1;x;s/#.*//;s/test/TEST/g;G;s/(.*)\n/\1/' file.txt
```

The advantage of this solution over the other solutions is that it will also work if there is a comment starting later in a line, as shown in the example below.
Since this solution uses the hold buffer of sed, this solution is not possible if you need to use the hold buffer for something else.

#### Input

```
test
# test
test # test
test
```

#### Output

```
TEST
# test
TEST # test
TEST
```

#### Explanation

1. `h;` - Save in hold buffer
2. `s/[^#]*//1;` - Remove everything before `#`
3. `x;` - Swap with hold buffer
4. `s/#.*//;` - Remove the comment
5. `s/test/TEST/g;` - Replace all occurences of `test` with `TEST`
6. `G;` - Append newline + hold buffer (the comment)
7. `s/(.*)\n/\1/` - Remove the last newline

The `-r` switch is required for using `\1`.

Answer (score 1):

awk:

```
awk '!/^[[:space:]]*#/ {gsub(/test/,"TEST")} 1' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -ne 'print $_ !~ /^\s*#/ ?gsub("test","TEST"):$_' file
```