# Ignore comments (#) using sed script, but keep the lines untouched

Tags: regex, shell, sed

This is similar to the following question:

[Ignore comments (#) using sed, but keep the lines untouched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798149/ignore-comments-using-sed-but-keep-the-lines-untouched)

However, the difference is that instead of having one substitution I have sed script-file with a couple of substitutions.

I guess I could edit each and every line of the script to be in the form:

```
/^#/!s/orig/replace/g
```

However, that seems to be a bit of too much copy-and-pasting to me.

Is there a more elegant way?

The script I am using is:

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/tokenizer.sed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a block:

```
/^#/!{s/a/b/;s/c/d/}
```

Comment: thanks! I didn't know that one can use a block at that point ... I transformed the scipt, but now getting `/bin/sed: file bin/tokenize2.sed line 2: extra characters after command` I'll transform the skript line-by-line now ...

Comment: @benroth: In some non-GNU seds, you might have to use a newline instead of a `;` to separate commands.

Comment: Works great now! Nice and clean!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use awk instead of sed in your script? A sed script of:

```
s/orig/replace/g
s/\(foo\)bar/\1dog/
```

can be converted line by line to a GNU awk script of:

```
{
   $0=gensub(/orig/,"replace","g")
   $0=gensub(/(foo)bar/,"\\1dog","")
}
{ print }
```

and then if you don't want to process lines that start with a # it's a trivial tweak to the awk script to test for that condition before entering the action block:

```
!/^#/ {
   $0=gensub(/orig/,"replace","g")
   $0=gensub(/(foo)bar/,"\\1dog","")
}
{ print }
```

Here's the first few conversions from your sed script to get you going if you want to do this:

```
# s=^"=`` =g
$0 = gensub(/^"/,"``","g")

# s=\([ ([{<]\)"=\1 `` =g
$0 = gensub(/([ ([{<])"/"\\1 ``","g")

# s=\.\.\.= ... =g
$0 = gensub(/\.\.\./," ... ","g")

# s=[,;:@#$%&]= & =g
$0 = gensub(/[,;:@#$%&]/," & ","g")

# s=\([^.]\)\([.]\)\([])}>"']*\)[       ]*$=\1 \2\3 =g
$0 = gensub(/([^.])([.])([])}>"']*)[    ]*$/,"\\1 \\2\\3","g")
```

mainly you just change `\(` in sed to `(` in awk, and `\1` in sed to `\\1` in awk.

Comment: Yeah, it seems however I do it, I have to write another pipe of unix tool commands to transform the script. :)

Comment: I was actually thinking you'd just take the 20 mins or so to convert your sed script to gawk by hand and then add the `!/^#/` in front of it.

Comment: sure, that's what I'll do - just thought there might be a simple addition to it that I didn't no so far.

Comment: I just did a few for you to put you on the right path. Make sure it's GNU awk you're using, though, as other awks don't have gensub() and so the conversion from sed would be much more difficult as it's only gensub() that supports backreferences.