# How to comment out only uncommented lines with Sed and leave blank/empty lines 100% intact?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I’m putting together some Bash configuration scripts to configure a Linux server and I would like to be able to comment all uncommented lines in a file, but leave blank/empty lines intact and untouched.

Using [the great answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4798161/117259) I was able to come up with this Sed one liner that works nicely:

```
sed -e '/^#/!s/\(.*\)/# \1/g' /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available
```

Of course when I run this Sed command on a production setup the `-e` will be swapped with `-i` to write the file in place, but anyway the contents of that file successfully are commented out as shown below:

```
#!/bin/sh
# 
# if [ -x /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available ]; then
#     exec /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available
# fi
```

But I would ideally like to have the output be something like this; note how the one blank/empty line is untouched.:

```
#!/bin/sh

# if [ -x /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available ]; then
#     exec /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available
# fi
```

Is there any way to do that in Sed?

Comment: I would like to suggest to "doubly comment" the already commented lines (`# # ` instead of `# `).  This way you can revert to the way it was before by simply removing one level of comments.  If you make everything just one level of comment, you have no way of knowing if it was commented before or you if you added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
sed -e 's/^\([^#].*\)/# \1/g' /etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend the address for `s` from `/^#/!` to `/^\(#.*\)\?$/!` (lines starting with `#`, or containing nothing).

Another way, in `awk`:

```
awk '$0 && $0 !~ /^#/ {printf "# "}1'
```

This adds `#` to each line that is not empty and does not start with `#`.

Comment: To modify the file directly (GNU awk): `awk -i inplace '$0 && $0 !~ /^#/ {printf "# "}1'`

Comment: @Smeterlink  note that if you're going to use `awk -i`, you'd better be sure there's no file named `inplace` or `inplace.awk` in the current directory: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749646/70524

Comment: Then how do you do it?

Comment: See the linked answer for details on using it safely