# Using sed to find a string and replace that line but ignore commented out lines

Tags: search, sed, replace

I am using sed to edit my /etc/samba/smb.conf files on 300 linux VMs with varying configurations.

I just want to search for the "server string =" line that is uncommented and replace that entire line with "server string = $VARIABLE SAMBA" which gets VARIABLE from a do-while loop as it reads my serverlist.

So trying to accomplish 3 things
1 - find "server string =" and replace that line with Server string = $VARIABLE"

```
      sed -i '/server string \=/c\server string = '$VARIABLE' SAMBA' /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

The command above works but unfortunately alot of my machines still have explanation comments that also include "server string ="   and I noticed the "server string =" line that is uncommented is not always in column 1 and is often spaced or tabbed in on older files so I can't just preface it with ^.

This is the command that I came up with reading other threads on stack overflow and combining the replace the line syntax (\c) with the ignore the commented lines syntax (^#/!/) but it isn't happy.
I added the \v for the "Magic substitution" from another post since figuring out exactly what needs escaped was eluding me.  (I thought the ^ and the = needed escaped)

```
      sed -i -e '/^#/!s/\vserver string =/c\server string = '$VARIABLE' SAMBA/g' /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

This line appears to not do anything for me at all now...no replacement, no variable substitution.

If I grep for "server string =" I see this :  (No I can't manually go change all 308 machines the same)

```
# server string = is the equivalent of the NT Description field
   server string = 145000web SAMBA ---- THIS LINE WAS NOT REPLACED ----
```

I am at my wits end with this.

### -----------------------------

Using the link provided by the first comment I get this :

`sed '/^#/!s/test/TEST/g' file.txt     - This command works as expected ignoring the commented out lines and replacing the text.`

Unfortunately trying to add in the c\ to replace the entire line goes awry :

```
cTEST
# test
# test
cTEST
a cTEST to find cTEST
```

The 3 uncommented lines should just say TEST
I have tried using the c\ after the s/ and that causes all substitution to fail.

Comment: I think this post might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798149/ignore-comments-using-sed-but-keep-the-lines-untouched

Comment: That is the post I used to ignore the commented lines....evidently I am misinterpreting the syntax somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For  file like this:

```
# server string = is the equivalent of the NT Description field
   server string = 145000web SAMBA1
#server string = is the equivalent of the NT Description field
       server string = 999999web2 SAMBA2
#   server string = another comment
#          server string = more comments
server string = some value SAMBA3
 server string = some value SAMBA4
```

and with a variable like this

```
echo $variable
111111www5
```

This will do the job with gnu sed, but white space is not preserved:

```
sed 's/^[^#]*server string \=.*/server string = '"$variable"' SAMBA/g' file
# server string = is the equivalent of the NT Description field
server string = 111111www5 SAMBA
#server string = is the equivalent of the NT Description field
server string = 111111www5 SAMBA
#   server string = another comment
#          server string = more comments
server string = 111111www5 SAMBA
server string = 111111www5 SAMBA
```

To preserve white space you can use something like this:

```
sed -r 's/(^[^#]*)server string \=.*/\1server string = '"$variable"' SAMBA/g' file
```

or even

```
sed -r 's/(^[^#]*server string \=).*/\1'"$variable"' SAMBA/g' file
```

PS: I have ommit `-i` switch on purpose. You can add it when you are happy with the results.

Comment: sed -i -r 's/(^[^#]*)server string \=.*/\1server string = '"$RNODE"' SAMBA/g' /etc/samba/smb.conf (your second command) works but doesn't preserver whitespace on this line, but does preserve whitespace on the workgroup = line using ----       sed -i -r 's/(^[^#]*)workgroup \=.*/\1 workgroup = MYCOMPANY SAMBA/g' /etc/samba/smb.conf   (I tried the 3rd command as well but fails  to preserver whitespace for the server string line still)

Comment: @NE1scott It sounds strange that whitespace is preserved under some situations and not in all situations. Give a try to this one : `sed -r 's/(^[^#]*[ \t]*)server string \=.*/\1server string = '"$variable"' SAMBA/g' file`

Comment: I was missing a space between \1 and server string.